# Is there a way to recover the data of unaccessible lines on the terminal?

Tags: command-line, data-recovery, data-loss

I am running an algorithm that regularly prints data on the terminal.
Unfortunately the terminal only shows a limited number of lines, the others are no longer accessible.
Are they deleted or can I recover the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible. There are a number of solutions (workarounds), however. Try these:

```
# scrolls page by page, only scrolls downwards
command |& more         

# scrolls line by line, can scroll up and down
command |& less      

# copies output to the file '~/file' (use '-a' argument to append)
command |& tee "~/file"   # displays in terminal as well

# redirects output to file '~/file' (use '>>' instead of '>' to append)
command 2>&1 > "~/file"
```

NOTE: 'redirect' does not display the output in the terminal (completely *redirecting* it to the file), 'copy' displays it in terminal *and copies* it to the file

Also, you should be able to set your terminal 'line buffer' to show more lines of command output (though it will still fill eventually)

To answer your question, the data is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

If the algorithm places what is printed in a text file, then you can view the data from within that file. Otherwise, the data does not exist. One way of solving the problem would be to direct the algorithm result to a textfile ,make the algorithm a cron job, then at regular intervals, you can use `cat textfile` to view the data. Let me know if you need more explanation on making it a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know how to recover from termial. But you can use alternate way. 
USE: **>>** and send output to a FILE and you can easily, see the complete data and if required save it for later use.
For eg:

```
 $ ls >>check.txt
```

It will send the the output of **ls** to **check.txt**

and

```
$./a.out >> test1.txt
```

Output after executing **a.out** is send to **text1.txt** file

HOpe it helps !!